# add to cart php session and get method

Tags: php, mysql, session

im trying to build a shopping cart program.

im having trouble in the add to cart part, using get method and session. can someone help me in my code? thanks

```
session_start();


if (isset($_GET['add'])) {

    $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']] + 1;


}


$query =  mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT id, name, description, price FROM products WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER BY id DESC  ");
$rows=  mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rows==0) {
    echo 'there is no product to display';
}
else
{

    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $id = $rows['id'];
        $name = $rows['name'];
        $description = $rows['description'];
        $price = $rows['price'];

        echo '<p>'.$id.'<br> '.$name.'<br>'.$description.'<br> '.number_format($price, 2).' <a href="cart.php? add='.$id.'">Add</a>  </p>'; 
    }

}echo $_SESSION['cart_'];
```

error

> Undefined index: cart_

Comment: help you how? errors if any? checking for them? doesn't look like it

Comment: error Undefined index: cart_

Comment: you're using this `+ '1'` as a string rather than an integer `+ 1` - Then this doesn't do much really `$_SESSION['cart_'];`

Comment: i changed it just now still same error..